# resilience4j Spring Boot 2

Tags: spring-boot, resilience4j

Trying out a simple **Spring Boot 2** + **Resilience4j** project.

But facing an issue that the **circuit breaker is always CLOSED** though the host application is down.

Service class

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}

@CircuitBreaker(name = "mainService", fallbackMethod="testFallBack")
public ResponseEntity<String> invokeService(int i) {
    return restTemplate.exchange(
            "http://localhost:9092/", // This service is always down
            HttpMethod.GET,
            null,
            String.class
    );
}

private  ResponseEntity<String> testFallBack(int i, Exception e) {
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("In fallback method", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

Resilience4J Config

```
management.endpoint.health.show-details: always
management.health.circuitbreakers.enabled: true

resilience4j:
  circuitbreaker:
    configs:
      default:
        registerHealthIndicator: true
        minimumNumberOfCalls: 5
        permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 3
        automaticTransitionFromOpenToHalfOpenEnabled: true
        waitDurationInOpenState: 5s
        failureRateThreshold: 50
        eventConsumerBufferSize: 10
    instances:
      mainService:
        baseConfig: default
```

The Service is being called multiple times from the Controller and I expect it to **fallback** after minimum 5 calls but the **circuit breaker is always CLOSED** and for each call from controller the host service is being called and up with Connection refused.

Dependencies: **spring-boot-starter-web, resilience4j-spring-boot2, spring-aop, spring-boot-starter-actuator**

Earlier I tried out programmatic approach using CircuitBreakerRegistry and Decorator Function which works as expected.

Comment: Could you please provide more context.
How do you invoke the `invokeService` method? From a different class, from the same class? Spring AOP does not work when invokeService is called from within the same class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you misunderstand the circuit breaker parameters. See the [documentation](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/circuitbreaker#create-and-configure-a-circuitbreaker):

> **minimumNumberOfCalls**, default: 100
>
> Configures the minimum number of calls which are required (per sliding window period) before the CircuitBreaker can calculate the error rate or slow call rate.
>
> For example, if minimumNumberOfCalls is 10, then at least 10 calls must be recorded, before the failure rate can be calculated.
> If only 9 calls have been recorded the CircuitBreaker will not transition to open even if all 9 calls have failed.
>
> **slidingWindowSize**, default: 100
>
> Configures the size of the sliding window which is used to record the outcome of calls when the CircuitBreaker is closed.

In your configuration, there is

```
minimumNumberOfCalls: 5
slidingWindowSize: 100  ## implicitly, because you have not set this parameters
```

And you

> expect it to fallback after minimum 5 calls

However, your circuit breaker opens after **100** failures, not after 5.